# Divisor function in clojure

Tags: function, clojure, functional-programming

I'm new to clojure and I want to create a function which returns a vector of all divisors of a certain Number.

For instance:
[1 2 3] for 6 as input

```
(defn div [x seq]
  (let [r  (range 1 (+ (/ x 2) 1)) ]   
    (dotimes [i (count (range 1 (+ (/ x 2) 1) ))]      
     (cond
      (= (mod x (nth r i )) 0)(print (conj  seq (nth r i ))) 
     ))))
```

This function returns the output in the following format:
[1][2][4][5][10][20][25][50] for 100 but I want to get the output in one vector. It seems that the seq variable is constantly overwritten with each loopstep. Could anyone explain this behaviour and provide me a workaround?

Thanks in advance and best regards

Comment: It's not that `seq` is "overwritten" with every step. It's that you never save the return value of `(conj seq (nth r i))`. You're thinking that `conj` should change `seq` "in place", but that's not how Clojure data structures work. When you use a function which "modifies" a data structure, the function will return the "new" data structure and the "old" one will be unchanged.

Answer (score 13):

You can avoid looping using a somewhat more idiomatic solution:

```
(defn divisors 
  [n]
  (filter (comp zero? (partial rem n)) (range 1 n)))
```

Comment: slight refactor
`(filter #(zero? (rem n %)) (range 1 n))`

Answer (score 4):

I think your approach is not correct, you can take a look to:

- the [loop](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/loop) function to resolve this kind of problems (i mean the cases where you need iterate and yield value),
- [iterate](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/iterate) function
- recursive functions (a function that calls itself)

And this code (using '[for](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/for)' function ) can easily resolve your specification

```
(let [n 100]
  (for [x (range 1 n)
       :when (zero? (rem n x))]
   x))
=>(1 2 4 5 10 20 25 50)
```

Comment: To misquote Obi-Wan: "Use the function, Luke!". My minimal experience with Clojure has taught me that looping over a collection is a classic case of Doing The Wrong Thing For All The Right Reasons and that There's A Better Way. (It's also Re-fighting The Last War - in this case, writing procedural code in a functional language).

Comment: Thanks @Bob_Jarvis! and replying Obi-Wan!,  "I thought i was using functions!"  , and... why does "loop" function exist?. Actually i prefer not to use "loop" but how do you maintain/update  state over the traversing of a collection (besides reduce [that only can work with one collection each time])?... and the 'for' function i think was designed for list comprehension (not exactly a looping function)

Comment: @tangrammer: Well, `reduce` is usually the answer. If you need to reduce two collections simultaneously (say, for some reason you have your keys in one collection and your values in the other), you can zip them together with `(map vector collection1 collection2 ...)` and then `(reduce (fn [memo [a b]] ...) zipped)`. It's not right to say that you should never use `loop` (since Clojure does not have tail-call elimination, it's necessary for some traditionally recursive algorithms), but it's one of those things that always makes me say, "Hmm, am I thinking about this the right way?"

Comment: @Chuck: Thanks for your comments! My current defense of loop function is related to this 4clojure problem http://www.4clojure.com/problem/82 I'm trying to modeling a dynamically data tree whose upper levels is determined by the downer levels of each branch. In the context of the problem: if you choose a word in your chain(branch) the next probable words are restricted  by the words in use. So the collections to reduce are defined on runtime based in the runtime data used. And with the `loop` function i can have 2 alternatives collections that are feeded themselves until data limit...

Answer (score 2):

Your fundamental problem is that you are attempting to take an imperative approach, but Clojure collections are immutable.  Also, I think that `dotimes` will always return `nil`, and `print` returns `nil` after printing its parameter(s).

There is a better way, but let's first see how we can use [atoms](http://clojure.org/atoms) to obtain an imperative solution:

```
(defn div [x seq]
  (let [r  (range 1 (+ (/ x 2) 1)) ]   
    (dotimes [i (count (range 1 (+ (/ x 2) 1) ))]      
      (cond
       ;; "Append" the ith element of r to seq
       ;; (Technically, we are replacing the value stored in seq
       ;; with a new list -- the result of conj-ing (nth r i)
       ;; to the current value stored in seq)
       (= (mod x (nth r i )) 0) (swap! seq conj (nth r i )))))  ;; <= don't print
  seq) ;; <== seq is what we're interested in, so we return it here.
       ;;     Otherwise, we would return the result of dotimes,
       ;;     which is nil
```

Note that we have eliminated the `print` and expect `seq` to be an atom (which we update using `swap!`).  We can now call `div` as follows:

```
user> (deref (div 6 (atom [])))
[1 2 3]
```

We could improve this by moving `seq` from the parameter list to a `let` inside the function, then dereferencing it when we return.  But it would be better to avoid mutation in the first place.  As tangrammer indicates in his answer, this is easily accomplished using `for`:

```
(defn div [x]
  (let [r (range 1 (+ (/ x 2) 1))]
    ;; Loop over r, taking only elements that are divisors of x
    (for [i r
          :when (= (mod x i) 0)]
      i))) ;; <= for accumulates the result of this expression (here simply i) into a sequence

user> (div 6)
(1 2 3)
```

In production code, you would probably inline `r` in this case, but I wanted to retain your original structure as much as possible.  We could also use `zero?` in the `:when` clause.  But all we're really doing in the for loop is a simple filter, so we could take [Guillermo's approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20248391/440294) and use `filter` instead.

Answer (score 1):

`div` takes an integer `x` and a sequence `seq` as arguments:

- it first declares `r` the range `1..(x/2)` ;
- it then iterates for `i` from `0` to `(count r)`, i.e. from `0` to `(x/2) - 1`:

  - for each `i`, it prints the result of `(conj seq (nth r i))`, i.e. the result of `(conj seq (+ i 1))`.

    Clojure uses immutable data structures which means that `(conj seq d)` returns a new sequence containing all of `seq`'s elements plus `d` ; in particular, if `seq` is the empty vector `[]`, it returns `[d]`.

End result: `(div n [])` prints `[d]` if `d` divides `x`, for each `d` from `1` to `(x/2)`.

Your code fails because you try to write Clojure code in an imperative way ; it is not standard (nor recommended), but possible by using mutable references e.g. [atoms](http://clojure.org/atoms) (see [@NathanDavis 's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20253010/2608009)) or [transient](http://clojure.org/transients) (mutable) data structures:

```
(defn div [n]
  (let [coll (transient [])]
    (dotimes [i (quot n 2)]
      (let [d (inc i)]
        (when (zero? (rem n d))
          (conj! coll d))))
    (persistent! coll)))
```

An idiomatic solution would use [`for`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/for) (as @tangrammer [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20248276/2608009)) ; it is not a loop structure (like in Java) but a macro that returns a lazy sequence:

```
(defn div [n]
  (for [:let [from 1                  ;; :let bindings are great for
              upto (inc (quot n 2))   ;; readability
              divides? #(zero?
                         (rem % %2))]

        d (range from upto)           ;; This binding form translates to
                                      ;; "each d from 1 to x/2".
                                      ;; You can have several binding forms
                                      ;; in a single for, to iterate over
                                      ;; several variables.

        :when (divides? n d)]         ;; Selects d only if it divides n.
                                      ;; You can also define termination
                                      ;; conditions with :while.

    d))                               ;; Each valid d is appended to a growing
                                      ;; lazy sequence i.e. a sequence that is
                                      ;; constructed the first time it is
                                      ;; traversed.
```

A `for` form with no body to speak of feels a bit abusive (though pleasing to the eye, IMHO) ; an alternative would be the filter displayed in [@GuillermoWinkler 's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20248391/2608009):

```
(defn divisors 
  [n]
  (->> (range 1 (inc (quot n 2)))     ;; the threading macros ->, ->> and .. are
       (filter #(zero? (rem n %)))))  ;; great to write sequence-manipulation
                                      ;; code as a sequence of step, though
                                      ;; maybe overkill in the present case
```

Comment: Last version has two small typos:

- short one trailing paren
- range should be 1..n/2 not 0..n/2

Comment: @rmp Thanks, I made the requested changes.